# How to connect ethers.js library with Rinkeby programmatically?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

According to [official docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--glossary) of **ethers.js**, this should be the way how to connect to a specific network like *Rinkeby*-testnet with custom data:

```
 const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(network, {
    etherscan: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    infura: INFURA_API_KEY,
```

Also, this would be the way to get a signer in order to sign transactions:

```
 const signer = provider.getSigner()
```

However, there is now method "getSigner" available on the default provider.

> TypeError: provider.getSigner is not a function

How to achieve that using ethers.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ethers.getDefaultProvider` seems to be somehow broken or outdated. Instead,
you should connect directly to a specific Provider, like this for Alchemy:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider("rinkeby", apiKey)
```

or for Infura:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider("rinkeby", apiKey)
```

After this, it is easy to get a signer:

```
const signer = provider.getSigner()
```

or

```
const walletSigner = wallet.connect(provider);
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/api-providers/).

Comment: I've also been trying to get a signer from InfuraProvider, but keep getting an error "API provider does not support signing (operation="getSigner", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.4.3)" Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @Vlad Please, check my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

getSigner() for InfuraProvider doesn't work, use this:

```
const infuraProvider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(network, API_KEY);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, infuraProvider);
const signer = wallet.connect(infuraProvider);
contract = new ethers.Contract(smartContractAddress, abi, signer);
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url)
const signer = provider.getSigner()
```

Got to know about this from the Alchemy [docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/introduction/getting-started#other-web3-libraries)

ethers.js [doc](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/#JsonRpcProvider-getSigner)